# Add image sytle information for an element from within ReplacedElementFactory of Flyingsaucer implementation class

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

I am using Flyingsaucer to generate PDF. I am trying to embed image in the pdf by implementing ReplacedElementFactory. I can generate pdf replaced with the image. No problem.

But what I wanted was to set the image height and width dynamically from within the class. I need to scale the image to a definite size. I will find the new scaled height and width of the image and want these scales to be set for the image embedded.

Can I add the style attribute in the Element fetched from BlockBox and update this element? Will this work? I tried using blackBox.setElement, but it does not work.

Could anyone help?

EDIT:

Peter Brant from flying saucer google group suggested the following

> Override getIntrinsicHeight / getIntrinsicWidth in your ReplacedElement implementation.  Note those values will be in render "dots" not pixels so you may have to scale appropriately.

But unfortunately it did not work for me. I overrode ReplaceElement of flying saucer and returned height and width. It did not work for me. The sample code I tried was here

```
public class MyITextImageElement implements ITextReplacedElement
{
      private final FSImage fsImage;
      private float[] scaledWidthAndHeight = null;

      public MyITextImageElement(FSImage image)
      {
        fsImage = image;

        try
        {
            ITextFSImage itextFSImage = (ITextFSImage) image;
            Image itextImage = itextFSImage.getImage();

            byte[] imageByteArr = itextImage.getOriginalData();
            //Getting scaled image height and width
            scaledWidthAndHeight = getScaledWidthAndHeight(imageByteArr);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Exception Handling
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth()
    {
        if (scaledWidthAndHeight != null)
        {
            return Math.round(scaledWidthAndHeight[0]);
        }
        return fsImage.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight()
    {
        if (scaledWidthAndHeight != null)
        {
            return Math.round(scaledWidthAndHeight[1]);
        }
        return fsImage.getHeight();
    }

      ...........
      ...........
}
```